# Shell script to cut the ps command output

Tags: shell, unix

How can I cut the `ps` command output to display one single process

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i httpd | grep -v grep

root     16786     1  0 Mar03 ?        00:01:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   17153 16786  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   17154 16786  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   17155 16786  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   17157 16786  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   17158 16786  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   17161 16786  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   17162 16786  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   17163 16786  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the main process:

```
ps -ef | grep 'httpd' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '$3 == 1'
```

(OR)

```
ps -ef | awk '/httpd/ && $3 == 1'
```

Here,

`$3` - Parent PID.

EDIT:

If you need just one line as output,

```
ps -ef | grep -m1 'httpd'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Now one more question, there are some servers running different process and i still need to print one,

Comment: 00:00:00 /bin/sh /app/opt/tomcat/bin/../instance1/bin/catalina.sh start
        00:00:00 cronolog /app/opt/tomcat/instance1/logs/catalina.%Y-%m-%d.out
        00:00:00 /bin/sh /app/opt/tomcat/bin/../instance2/bin/catalina.sh st

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which process it is, you can just cut the output after the first line with `head -1`.

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i httpd | grep -v grep | head -1
root     16786     1  0 Mar03 ?        00:01:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

If you need to find the mother process, you can add the `-H` option to the ps, which (in addition to indenting the child processes to make a nice process tree/forest) orders the processes so that the parent is always listed before the children.

```
$ ps -efH | grep -i httpd | grep -v grep | head -1
root     16786     1  0 Mar03 ?        00:01:02   /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help